# How to put a text input box in a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please can someone tell me how to put a input text box in a dropdown just as this :-

[image: exmple]

this pic was using bootstrap. I dont want bootstrap just want to use html/css and javascript maybe? pleas ehelp me i stuck on this quite long.

Comment: Here's an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyQYmN. This post can be improved by explaining what you tried so far and what concepts you found when researching the problem that are hard to understand. EDIT: This example requires bootstrap (css & js)

Answer (score 0):

Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyQYmN

HTML tags can be nested in eachother. Given this, you can change the dropdown's HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>An option</li>
  <li>Another option</li>
  <li>Something else here</li>
</ul>
```

to include the `<input type="text">`.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without bootstrap you will have to make your own CSS that will treat a list as a drop-down.
-one way to do this is explained here http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Create-Custom-CSS3-Dropdown-Menus-CSS-Drop/?ALLSTEPS

now that you have a list that is treated like a drop down, you can add any element you want in it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo that uses pure CSS3 as a dropdown menu and added an input for you. Here is the code to accomplish this, demo is at the bottom.

```
/* Set Dropdown Display to None*/
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

/* Display Dropdown on hover*/

nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
}

ul li{
 display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul li a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
    background: #222222; 
  border-radius: 0px; 
    position: absolute; 
}

nav ul ul li{
  padding: 15px 0;
}

nav ul ul li a{
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .5;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover{
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

CSS3 Dropdown Menu: [DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/GpJKqP?editors=110)